# Relationship between RMSE and RSS

Tags: regression, residuals, error

I'm working on simple linear regression, and I would like to understand the relationship between RMSE and RSS (residual sum of squares).

In [another Stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110999/r-confused-on-residual-terminology), I found some explanations, but they didn't directly explain the answer to my particular question, and definitely not in a way I could understand.

What is the relationship between RMSE and RSS in linear regression?

Comment: RMSE = RSS/sqrt(# of residuals), I presume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the mathematical derivations, you might ask yourself why use one measure over the other to assess the performance of a given model? You could use either, but the advantage of RMSE is that it will come out in more interpretable units. For example, if you were building a model that used house features to predict house prices, RSS would come out in dollars squared and would be a really huge number. RMSE would come out in dollars and its magnitude would make more sense given the range of your house price predictions.

Answer (score 17):

- The [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) is the sum of the square of the errors (difference between calculation and measurement, or estimated and real values):

$ RSS = \sum{(\hat Y_i-Y_i)^2} $

- The [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is the mean of that sum of the square of the errors:

$ MSE = \frac{1}{n}\sum{(\hat Y_i-Y_i)^2}$

- The [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) is the square root of the MSE:

$ RMSE = \sqrt{MSE} $

A bit of math shows:

$ RMSE = \sqrt{MSE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \cdot RSS} $

You can check it in the [example that you posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110999/r-confused-on-residual-terminology):

$ RMSE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{32} \cdot 447.6743} = 3.740297 $

Note that for the [mtcars dataset](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/datasets/mtcars) $n=32$.

---

Also see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197188/what-is-the-difference-between-rss-and-ssr)

Comment: Wait wait wait, then why is MSE not called MRS (Mean of Residual Squared)???

Comment: @NoName  It was like that when I got here! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: While we're protesting naming conventions, why is RSS not called SSR (sum of square residuals)?!

Comment: @gwelter Because `sum of square residual` and `residual sum of square` mean the same thing. But `mean of squared error` and `mean of squared residual` can mean very different thing as in regression residual is used to estimate error. But to get back to the point I have the same question as @NoName.